How do I force the UI to reload with Jetpack Compose?
I have a GameState object which gets updated whenever the state of the game changes, and some of the UI doesn't update properly. I would like to just call a reload function whenever the data reloads so I don't have to worry about it not updating.
package dev.madcatter.lostworld

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Refresh
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Settings
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBar
import androidx.compose.material3.VerticalDivider
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import dev.madcatter.lostworld.data.GameState
import dev.madcatter.lostworld.ui.Console
import dev.madcatter.lostworld.ui.Turns
import dev.madcatter.lostworld.ui.theme.LostWorldTheme
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var myApp: LostWorldApp
    private lateinit var gameState: MutableState<GameState>
    private var updateTicker: MutableState<Int> = mutableStateOf(0)

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        myApp = application as? LostWorldApp ?: throw IllegalStateException("Application class is not LostWorldApp")
        gameState = mutableStateOf(myApp.gameState!!)

        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            LostWorldTheme {
                MainContent()
            }
        }
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    @Composable
    private fun MainContent() {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    title = { Text(text = "Lost World") },
                    actions = {
                        IconButton(onClick = {
                            gameState.value.debug("---\n\nReload button clicked.")
                            reloadGameState()
                        }) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Default.Refresh,
                                contentDescription = "Reload"
                            )
                        }
                        IconButton(onClick = {
                            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, SettingsActivity::class.java))
                        }) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Default.Settings,
                                contentDescription = "Settings"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                )
            },
            content = { innerPadding ->
                // Main content here
                Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                    Turns(
                        gameState.value,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(16.dp)
                            .weight(0.25f)
                            .fillMaxHeight()
                    )

                    VerticalDivider(
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(1.dp)
                            .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                            .fillMaxHeight(0.85f)
                    )

                    Console(
                        gameState.value,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(16.dp)
                            .weight(0.75f)
                            .fillMaxHeight()
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        // Run the reload after a short delay using lifecycleScope
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            delay(200) // Wait 200 milliseconds, or adjust as necessary
            reloadGameState()
        }
    }

    private fun reloadGameState() {
        gameState.value.reload()
        gameState.value = myApp.gameState!!
        updateTicker.value++
    }
}

What I tried:

I used onStart() to reload gameState whenever the activity comes to the foreground, adding a small delay to let the UI settle.
To refresh the UI, I reassigned gameState, which sometimes resulted in the output being cleared.
Reassigning gameState led to issues with clearing state, like losing console output.
Now I'm exploring how to best update only necessary properties of gameState to trigger a UI refresh without losing existing data.


You should never manually update the UI when using jetpack compose. It just kills the reason of working on a compose application. I can see that this is your game object.
gameState: MutableState<GameState>

If you need jetpack compose to update the UI when the state of the object changes. You must use the remember API. So, if you change your object like below, your UI should automatically update.
var state by remember{
mutableStateOf(myApp.gameState!!)
}

After updating your implementation like above, you will no longer need to reference your object by using ".value" as you have added "by" keyword instead of "=".
For just updating specific properties of an object and expect the UI to be updated you can use the copy function to make it work.
state = state.copy(prop = ?)

I hope this helps.

I don't have a copy method on GameState.

copy function is an extension provided by Kotlin. If you use the remember API on game state then you should be able to use the copy function.

@AhsanZia: "copy function is an extension provided by Kotlin" -- no, it is a generated function, generated on a data class. If GameState is not a data class, it will not have a supplied copy() function.

I made it a data class, so now I have a copy method. Now the issue is that val cannot be reassigned.

If you need to reassign a variable, you must use "var" instead of "val". As an example, I have updated the state variable in my answer from val to var.

It still says that when I change it to var.

Can you please show your updated code?

https://pastebin.com/7niWnQhW

I see that you are trying to update the gameState object that is being passed from the let function but not the original gameState object (which is var).
gameState?.let { gameState ->}. It would be best if you can change the param name of the lambda expression. Then finally, in the onStart function you can keep the gameState object and it should work.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
